# Passing class/instance attributes to static methods in Python

Tags: python, class, optimization, static-methods

Does it make sense to pass attributes of instance/class (`self.something`) to a static method of the same class?
Example without static method:

```
from intel import i5
from kingston import ddr3
from windows import Prompt


class PC:

    def __init__(self, username, password, cpu, ram):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.cpu = cpu
        self.ram = ram

    def _log_in(self, login_prompt):
        login_prompt.enter(self.username, self.password)

    def start_up(self):
        # boot_up and do stuff...
        login_prompt = Prompt()
        self._log_in(login_prompt)
        # auto-run applications and do stuff...
```

Example with static method:

```
from intel import i5
from kingston import ddr3
from windows import Prompt


class PC:

    def __init__(self, username, password, cpu, ram):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.cpu = cpu
        self.ram = ram

    @staticmethod
    def _log_in(login_prompt, username, password):
        login_prompt.enter(username, password)

    def start_up(self):
        # boot_up and do stuff...
        login_prompt = Prompt()
        self._log_in(login_prompt, self.username, self.password)
        # auto-run applications and do stuff...
```

In both cases usage would be the same:

```
my_computer = PC('user', 'password', i5, ddr3)
my_computer.start_up()
```

Comment: Your first block of code is easier to read.

Comment: Both implementations are correct and functionnaly equivalent so it's really a matter of context and personal tastes.

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong

```
@staticmethod
def _log_in(self, login_prompt, username, password):
    login_prompt.enter(username, password)
```

A static method will not receive `self`, which is the instance. You do not get a implicit reference to the instance in a static method. You can think of a static method as a plain function, but called from a instance.

If you do not intend to expose `_log_in`, do not provide arguments and only use `self` inside it.